# Salesforce checkmarx security warning : Bulkify Apex Methods Using Collections In Methods

Tags: apex

i having some problem in salesforce checkmarx report. this  generated one waring 
: Bulkify_Apex_Methods_Using_Collections_In_Methods in particular code

```
        interested_prop = String.escapeSingleQuotes(interested_prop);            
        String qry = 'select ' + sObjectUtility.sObjectFields('srex__Matches__c') +' Id from Matches__c';
        string whereString = ' where Interested_in_Dealing__c = false';
        whereString       += ' AND ('+ sObjName + ' =: propid ';
        whereString       += ' OR '+ lookup2 +' =: propid )';
        whereString       += ' AND ('+ sObjName + ' =: interested_prop ';
        whereString       += ' OR '+ lookup2 +' =: interested_prop )';


        list<Matches__c> matches = Database.query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(qry)+String.escapeSingleQuotes(whereString));

        if(matches.size() > 0){
            matches[0].Interested_in_Dealing__c = true;
            try{
                update matches;
            }catch(Exception ex){
                system.debug('Error occurred while perfoming DML Operation :::::'+ ex.getMessage());
            }
        }else{
            Matches__c new_match = new Matches__c();
            new_match.put(sObjName, prop_id);
            new_match.put(lookup2 , interested_prop);
            new_match.Interested_in_Dealing__c = true;
            try{
                List<Matches__c> matchlst = new List<Matches__c>();
                matchlst.add(new_match);
                insert matchlst;
            }catch(Exception ex){
                system.debug('Error occurred while perfoming DML Operation :::::'+ ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

pls help me out.

Comment: can u post ur complete code.. is this inside a method which is being called in a loop ?

Answer (score 2):

Per Salesforce [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm) regarding **for loop soql formats**

1. The single sObject format executes the for loop's  once
   per sObject record. Consequently, it is easy to understand and use,
   but is grossly inefficient if you want to use data manipulation
   language (DML) statements within the for loop body. Each DML
   statement ends up processing only one sObject at a time.
2. The sObject list format executes the for loop's  once
   per list of 200 sObjects. Consequently, it is a little more
   difficult to understand and use, but is the optimal choice if you
   need to use DML statements within the for loop body. Each DML
   statement can bulk process a list of sObjects at a time.

You could try #2. Example below:

```
for(List<Matches__c> listOfMatches : [Select Id, Name from Matches__c]){
  for(Integer i=0; i<listOfMatches.size(); i++){
    //data manipulation logic
  }
  update listOfMatches;
}
```

I have done something like mentioned above to get rid of this warning from Checkmarx.